# Ansible Best Practices and ansible.cfg

Tags: ansible

I'm reading the about [alternative diretory layout](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/playbooks_best_practices.html#alternative-directory-layout) for ansible to organize my playbooks, roles and everythin else but i'm missing how to configure the ansible.cfg to be able to use it.

How does ansible figure out where my inventories is in a directory layout like `$ANSIBLE_HOME/inventories/production/hosts.yml` wihtout pass the full path to `-i` like the examples in the mentioned links do?

Consider `$ANSIBLE_HOME` where my playbooks will be stored.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For `ansible.cfg` there is a documented parameter [`inventory`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/intro_configuration.html#inventory):

> This is the default location of the inventory file, script, or directory that Ansible will use to determine what hosts it has available to talk to:
>
> ```
> inventory = /etc/ansible/hosts
> ```

Comment: Yes, i know about the `inventory` parameter in the `ansible.cfg`. The thing is, the alternative directory layout proposed will have hosts files under sub-directories. Example, if i have my inventory configured to point to the following directory: `inventory = /etc/ansible/inventories/`.  And inside it i create something like `development/hosts.yml`, `production/hosts.yml` how to instruct ansible to find these inventory files ?

Comment: You can't do it the way you want.

Comment: Well.. i will need to play around with the `ansible.cfg` and the `-i` switch to find out how to do this. I will update here with my findings. For a while, you answer is correct @techraf. Thanks :)

Comment: As a last comment even if my `ansible.cfg` have the parameter `inventory` configured to `/etc/ansible/inventories`, to use subdirectories like i want, i will need to use the `-i`switch and pass the path where the inventory file live. Thanks again for the help :)